# dualboot ubuntu / windows - Can I compress shared NTFS drive?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

I can acces the drive just fine on both OS'es.
my idea now is to compress it in windows.
Will it keep working as it does now?

Comment: If you formatted the disk in Ubuntu and now you don’t see it in Windows you probably formatted it in ext4 format or something like that. You should be able to see it in Windows Disk Management but not the Windows file explorer if this is the case. You should be able to format again (ntfs) and compress it in Windows. Then you probably want to edit your fstab file to automount the disk when you start Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't my question. The question was if compressing it in windows will prohibit it from working on ubuntu. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I think you may have changed your question since my comment when the problem seemed to be accessing the partition from Windows. Apologies if I confused this with another question. I would expect you to be able to compress in Windows and access from Ubuntu but I’ve never done that to be sure. If the partition is empty or you have a backup of the data then try it and see. I’ve found examples of people having problems with this if they compress from Ubuntu but not the other way round

Comment: I will just do it and let you know, than we all will have an answer. :) Worst case scenario my second drive becomes (temporarily) unavailable in ubuntu, but I get to keep using it in windows (wich is what I use most of the time now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried compressing my second drive (1tb nvme ssd) in windows and can confirm it was still accesible in ubuntu. :-)